# How can I create a row for every 3rd column in Razor mvc5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently trying to add a new row for each 3rd column with razor. However, with the current code, only the first three columns get wrapped in a row, and the rest get skipped. I have been looking around for a fix, but none of it seems to work with my code. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```html
@model IEnumerable<Byporten.createpost>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutClient.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">

    @{
        var itemCount = 0;
    }

    @while (itemCount < 3)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Reverse().Take(9))
        {
            if(itemCount == 0 )
            {
                @:<div class="row">
            }

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="image-section">
                    <img src="~/images/uploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL)"/>
                </div>
                <div class="title-section">
                    <h5><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h5>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Les mer", "viewArticle", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
            </div>

            itemCount++;

            if ((itemCount % 3) == 0)
            {
                @:</div>
            }

        }
        
    }
    @{itemCount = 0;}
</div>
```

Comment: `@while (itemCount < 3)` is only going to render 3 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to result in invalid markup because `itemCount == 0` will be true only once. Replace `if (itemCount == 0)` with `if (itemCount % 3 == 0 || itemCount % 3 == 3)`.

I would also get rid of the `while` loop and the `itemCount` reset at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me, but the following did:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    var itemCount = 0;
    foreach (var listItem in ((ListViewModel)item).ListItemViewModel.Items)
    {
        if (itemCount == 0)
        {
            @:<div class="row">
        }

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#" data-sf-role="toggleLink" class="organogram-title"><span class="organogram-outter-ring"></span>@listItem.Fields.Title</a>
            <div style="display:none;" class="sf-list-content">
                @Html.Raw(listItem.Fields.Content)
            </div>
            <div class="organogram-outter-ring"></div>
        </div>

        if (itemCount == 2)
        {
            itemCount = 0;
            @:</div>
        }
        else
        {
            itemCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.Raw()` method to avoid compilation problems with conditional closing tag, and temp variable `insertRow` to avoid repeating in row condition:

```
<div class="container">

@{
    var itemCount = 0;
}

@{
    foreach (var item in Model.Reverse().Take(9))
    {
        var insertRow = itemCount % 3 == 0;

        if(insertRow)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<div class="row">")
        }

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="image-section">
                <img src="~/images/uploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL)"/>
            </div>
            <div class="title-section">
                <h5><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h5>
                @Html.ActionLink("Les mer", "viewArticle", new { id = item.Id })
            </div>
        </div>

        if (insertRow)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</div>")
        }

        itemCount++;
    }
}
</div>
```

And also `while (itemCount < 3)` loop is look strange and unnecessary for your task.

Answer (score 0):

So, I know I am a little late to the game and there is an accepted answer, however, I want to add my rendition because it requires no duplicate `if` statements and no code compilation squigglies.

My approach uses an inner for loop based on the number of columns you want to have before creating a new row:

```
<table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                     <td><b>My List Data:</b></td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                @{
                   var items = Model.MyList;
                   const int colCount = 2;
                }
                @for (var i = 0; i < items.Count(); i += colCount)
                {
                  <tr>
                        @for (var c = 0; c < colCount && i + c < items.Count(); c++)
                        {
                            <td>@(items[i + c].Display):</td>
                        }
                  </tr>
                }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

The premise is to determine what your column count is, that is show above using `const int colCount =2;`

Then, loop, using a `for` loop, on your list but instead of incrementing by 1, as is traditional, increment by your `colCount` value.

Then, have your row tag.  This means a row will be created every n+colCount items.

Within that row tag, have another for loop that increments by 1 until you either reach your colCount OR your parent iterator plus your colCount iterator equals or exceeds the total items in your list.

Within that for loop, simply create a cell that is at the index of `i` (outer iterator) + `c` (colCount) iterator.

This gives you a nice left to right, top to bottom table structure from a flat list without extra if statements and compilation warnings.